# Lack of data from Sentinel 2 over part of the territory until 2019

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image, sentinel

When searching for Sentinel images, I couldn't find some of the images from 2017-2018. With what it can be connected? I've tried various methods, creating an image with both mosaic() and median(), but some of the images are missing.

Sample code I used:

```
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[33.654919491726645, 49.74657916999263],
          [33.654919491726645, 46.3553630474863],
          [38.752575741726645, 46.3553630474863],
          [38.752575741726645, 49.74657916999263]]], null, false);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
.filterDate('2017-08-01', '2017-08-30')
.mean()
.clip(geometry)

  var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.centerObject(geometry);

Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'RGB');
```

Comment: SR product was introduced at that time. Before that year the only way to obtain SR scenes was by using Sen2Cor (with CLI or using SNAPsoftware). Then, ESA uploaded processed images but with global coverage as it does nowadays

Comment: Maybe the issue is to do with what is discussed in the sentinel technical guide, they don't capture images which fall below a threshold in land mass? You don't state where in the world you are trying to collection days for.

Comment: I share the same opinion as @aldo_tapia; however, if you wish to confirm it, you can try to see if there are images using the Sentinel-2 1C collection `ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")`.

Comment: I was looking for a part of the images over the territories of the Zaporozhye region. I rechecked the available images in this region. Image does not fully cover it in 2017.